# Coloring the value of pandas dataframe through its diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a pandas dataframe, which is used for heatmap colouring. I want to colour the value along the diagonals of the dataframe. If the diagonal contains five values as [-1,2,0,-2,5], I want to colour them as 0 in 'white', then 2 in lighter red, 5 in darkest red, and then -1 in a lighter blue, -2 in darkest blue (Just to indicate the intensities between the values, where darker reds go with the positive value and darker blues goes with the negative value). The example code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
list1 = [[10],[5,-2],[-1,2,-3],[4,-5,3,-2]]
dfff = pd.DataFrame(l1)
print (dfff)
sns.heatmap(dfff,square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

I want the diagonals to be coloured, like for the first instance, the first diagonal would be [10,-2,-3,-2]. I want them to be coloured as 10 with darkest red, 2-,-3,-2 in the shades of blue according to their intensities.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the diagonals by saying

```
for i, row in enumerate(list1):
    row[i] == *whatever*
```

Not sure what you want to set them to though

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
l1 = [[10],[5,-2],[-1,2,-3],[4,-5,3,-2]]
dfff = pd.DataFrame(l1)

for x, c in zip(range(1,dfff.shape[0]+1), ['Blues','Reds','Purples','Oranges']):
    sns.heatmap(dfff.mask(dfff.notna().cumsum().gt(x), np.nan), square=True, linewidths=.5, cmap=c,  mask=dfff.mask(~dfff.notna().cumsum().gt(x-1), np.nan).isna())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply. But the requirement was a bit different, I need the positive values to be in the shades of reds and negative values to be in the shades of blues. As an ex, Here for the first diagonal, 10 would be the darkest red, and then 2-,-3,-2 be in the shades of blues according to their intensities.

Comment: So just change the color map to a diverging red blue